# HTML5 input file image capture images upside down

Tags: html, image, file, input, capture

I have implemented a input file image capture in my web app to let an user take a picture and upload it. However, the image appears upside down when they have the tablet upside down. When using the camera app outside the app, it doesn't matter how you take the picture, its always upside up.

How can I force this in my web app?

Comment: When uploading the file you can try and test for metadata defining the `orientation` of the image and then rotate the image appropriately on the server when you're saving the uploaded file data. However to have a concise answer to this we'd need to know your server code (ex. `PHP`? `Perl`?) you're using to handle the upload.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with iOS taking upside down picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676333/how-to-deal-with-ios-taking-upside-down-picture)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the window orientation using javascript

```
function readDeviceOrientation() {

switch (window.orientation) {  
case 0:  

    // Portrait 
    break; 

case 180:  

    // Portrait (Upside-down)
    break; 

case -90:  

    // Landscape (Clockwise)
    break;  

case 90:  

    // Landscape  (Counterclockwise)
    break;
}
```

[documentation](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-orientation/)

Comment: I *think* OP rather wants the image to rotate rather than the device

Comment: @Marin, excuse me if i'm not understanding.. The above let's you know the rotation of the "device"? Once you know the ration you can write additional scripts to rotate the video/photo?

Comment: I understood that the uploaded image was always the wrong way round (180deg rotation) compared to device, device rotation wasn't the issue but that image was saved on the server incorrectly rotated. Sorry if we're confusing each other!

Comment: @Martin just reread the OP's question and you're correct. The picture is always 180 deg regardless of rotation. My mistake sorry.