# Rotate Base64 image data with HTML 5 canvas: final transformation is cropped and wrongly translated

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, base64

I have a functionality in a web app that opens up a Bootstrap modal window on uploading a profile picture. It allows the user to crop and finalize the profile display.

I found out that sometimes the orientation of photos can be messed up. I added a few parts to check the EXIF orientation data of the images and rotate and fix them accordingly. Now even though it looks like the logic is right, I can't wrap my head around the context and canvas concept of HTML 5 because the end result quite obviously shows I'm missing something.

Here is the modal load handler:

```
$("#imageJcrop").on ("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {

            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
              var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              canvas.height = img.height;
              canvas.width = img.width;
              var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
              //..check orientation data, this code assumes the case where its oriented 90 degrees off
              ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
              ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
              $(".editPhoto").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));

              $('<img id="cropbox" class="img-responsive" exif="true" src="' + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") + '">').load(function() {
                spinner.stop();
                $(this).appendTo($("#imageJcrop .modal-body #cropbox-container"));
                 $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                                onChange: update_crop,
                                onSelect: update_crop,
                                setSelect: [0, 0, 300, 300],
                                aspectRatio: 1,
                                bgColor: 'white'
                                });

              });

            }; });
```

(I can't post the images so I'm pasting the imgur links here)

The actual image without the above code being applied:
http://i.imgur.com/jffkaUu.png

After applying the HTML5 canvas and context transformation
http://i.imgur.com/D9qQKHZ.png

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/blob/master/js/load-image-orientation.js  - I think you are missing translation of the axes.

However, consider if you may just want to use their plugin directly, because there are too many EXIF cases to think about, as I discovered for myself earler when dealing with [client-side javascript EXIF rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images/20600801)