# How to get correct image without sideways using css or jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an upload form which works fine for uploading an image. I was not able to see the image in correct rotation. Here is the example in which I wrote a css to show you the correct rotation:

```
 <style>
    .as {
       transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    }
  </style>


<!-- orignal image -->
<img src="http://www.thediscerningbrute.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Men__3_flat.jpg">

    <!-- orignal image -->
    <!-- i am getting image like this -->    
<img src="http://www.thediscerningbrute.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Men__3_flat.jpg" class="as">
    <!-- i am getting image like this -->
```

Comment: can you post your complete HTML? I've tried this in fiddler and sounds good, 2nd image which has a `class="as"` working fine.

Comment: yes it is working. http://jsfiddle.net/s8rxdqsg/

Comment: actually  when i get image from folder using php i am getting not getting image in right position which i uploaded

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/salmanaashish/g3xxfzn3/      you will understand how i am getting

Comment: what u are trying say ....not understood

Comment: i am not getting image like original  image

Comment: did u see image in folder in correct angle means without rotation. I thing it is uploaded with rotation. Thats why your are not able to see in correct angle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images does this help ?

Comment: What is your question. Are you trying to rotate an image? You've already clearly achieved that with CSS, so please help us understand what your problem is.

Comment: i am using php may be  Load Image Exif Parser extension  i want

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to EXIF
Some image files contain EXIF information inside like rotation, datetime, location etc
Your PHP code might be discarding the EXIF when saving it

Comment: is there is any solution my problem is which i upload image i am not  getting same like original image its rotating

Comment: @user4557928 did you read my earlier comment and will you clarify your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this library [Library](https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/)

If you include the Load Image Exif Parser extension, the parseMetaData callback data contains the additional property exif if Exif data could be found in the given image.
The exif object stores the parsed Exif tags:

```
var orientation = data.exif[0x0112];
```

It also provides an exif.get() method to retrieve the tag value via the tag's mapped name:

```
var orientation = data.exif.get('Orientation');
```