# Remove exif in AngularJS at upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, web

I have a web application (using AngularJS) in which users can upload a profile picture and before saving the image they can adjust they photo with some cropping tool.

The issue is that when I'm uploading photos taken with an iPhone in portrait mode, all this images are rotated 90 degrees. The only way that images are uploaded correctly is if the user takes the picture in landscape mode (iPhone oriented with volume buttons pointing down).

I need a solution to make this work, no matter phone orientation when taking pictures.

[`My example`](http://jsfiddle.net/hclaudiu/8wqx3uxz/2/)

Comment: IPhone images have a info about Orientation you can use that to rotate exact orientation you want in server. What server language you use?

Comment: PHP with Mongo DB. But I don't want to make the image rotation on the server.

Comment: If you want in client side then maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images