# Picture orientation determination from phone

Tags: exif

Is using the EXIF data to determine the orientation flag of an image safe? As in is it standardized?

I found this stackoverflow question about the flags, but is it standardized across cameras?

[JS Client-Side Exif Orientation: Rotate and Mirror JPEG Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images)

Answer (score 0):

I found this doc here, http://www.exiv2.org/Exif2-2.PDF

Which shows the standardized flags used for determining orientation/rotation