# Fix blob image orintaion without using Canvas - EXif rotaion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

we have some code for image upload and preview using jquery .Please see this fiddle and code .

https://jsfiddle.net/28v6vd23/1/

```js
 function readURL() { 
     var fileList = this.files;
     var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
     var ValidImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];
        
        
    for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
   var file_allow = fileList[i];
      var fileType = file_allow["type"];
   if ($.inArray(fileType, ValidImageTypes) > 0) {
        var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
      var ran_x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000000) + 1);
     $('.new').append('<div class="my-img-div" style="width:auto; display:inline-block;" ><img  src="' + objectUrl + '" class="my-img" id="" /></div>');
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    }
        }     
        
   }

  var inputfile= document.getElementById("inputFile");
  inputfile.addEventListener("change",readURL,false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="inputFile" />
   
</form>

<div class="new">

</div>
```

here for some images  the image is previewing correctly ,

but for some images it is rotating 90 degree. Please check this .

Please check with this image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UVW6dXMESAkeRFVxwBfsWWa4e9xD-DIL/view

How we can solve this ?

> UPDATE

From [@qvotaxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604086/qvotaxon) answer i can understand that https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image this will help to solve the problem . But when i look into this i am struggling with the integration . If anyone can help the integration with my current code it will be really helpful .

Thank you

Comment: Actually your code is ok but image captured horizontally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Client-Side Exif Orientation: Rotate and Mirror JPEG Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images)

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of the image is probably stored in the EXIF-data. Have a look at this post [JS Client-Side Exif Orientation: Rotate and Mirror JPEG Images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600801/3604086)
 for a solution.