# Firebase storage change image orientation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

How do I change the orientation of an image that I uploaded to Firebase Storage?

I believe that an image has the exif data which describes the orientation of an image. How can I change this?

Comment: Firebase Storage doesn't have any feature that's going to help you with this directly.  If you want to manipulate exif data, you should probably be doing that in your app using some image manipulation library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Client-Side Exif Orientation: Rotate and Mirror JPEG Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images)