# Nginx image_filter resize loses metadata

Tags: nginx

When resizing an image with Nginx image_filter it rotates the image if the image is too big, how can I resize an image without losing the metadata of the image?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most probably not the nginx image_filter, but the image itself doesn't include the metadata (happens sometimes when the image is captured in vertical mode on phones). 
There are 3 fixes you can do

1. add the `image-orientation: from-image` CSS property. (works in firefox and safari on iOS)
2. Have JS read the Exif data and rotate the image accordingly with CSS. more info how to read the EXIF data in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images)
3. When uploading the image resample it with something like the `-auto-orient` function from image-magic. that will regenerate the orientation metadata.

Hope this helps you.