# How to adjust the orientation of a image in order to show proper preview of the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, exif

[image][image][image]I have developed a laravel web application which has a function of accepting images uploaded by users and then display it. I had encountered  a problem while testing as photos uploaded using mobile phones were rotating 90 degrees in anti clock wise direction I used image intervention to solve that issue . But as i am showing a preview of the uploaded image to the users using javascript the images are rotated 90 degrees but when i save the image it becomes proper. 
My javascript code is

```
    function imagePreview(input,elm) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $(elm).css("background-image","url('"+e.target.result+"')");
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#settings_img").on("change",function(){
        imagePreview(this,"#settings_img_elm");
    });
```

can anyone please help me to properly orient the preview image by editing the code above so that the orientation of the image changes when needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS Client-Side Exif Orientation: Rotate and Mirror JPEG Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images)

Comment: i tried those codes but i couldnt get a proper output i am new in web development and therefore i want someone to edit my code for me@Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just rotating the image with CSS?

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    $(elm).css({
        "background-image":"url('"+e.target.result+"')",
        "transform": "rotate(90deg)"
    });
}
```

---

**Edit:** Well, after a brief dive into the world of EXIF data, I think I might have a solution for you.  I borrowed Ali's [getOrientation()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490603/1195615) function, as @Nick suggested, and then I just corrected the orientation with CSS as follows:

```
function correctOrientation(element, orientation){
    switch (orientation) {
      case 2: $(element).css("transform", "scaleX(-1)");
        break;
      case 3: $(element).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
        break;
      case 4: $(element).css("transform", "rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1)");
        break;
      case 5: $(element).css("transform", "rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1)");
        break;
      case 6: $(element).css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
        break;
      case 7: $(element).css("transform", "rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1)");
        break;
      case 8: $(element).css("transform", "rotate(-90deg)");
        break;
      default: break;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5sm7ucf/1/)

And if you need example files to test it, [get them here](https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples).

---

**Edit:** Placing the uploaded image in an `<img>` instead of the div's background-image:
https://jsfiddle.net/ynzvtLe2/2/

Comment: the problem with this is there are phones which previews image with proper orientation, therefore css rotate will mess with those images@thingEvery

Comment: i just want to know how to put this in my code i am new in this field could u please put this code in the above given code in the question

Comment: @JeffrinJose Yeah, bro. I did that. Just go here https://jsfiddle.net/n5sm7ucf/1/ and copy everything from the javascript box. (Replace your JS code with that.)  Oh, you'll need the CSS too.  Although, you can use jQuery to add that programmatically if you really wanted to, just as you did in your 'imagePreview' function.

Comment: @JeffrinJose If you're still stuck, @ me.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help i am actually using php for uploading and displaying file only the preview part is done by js i am working on laravel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205033/discussion-between-thingevery-and-jeffrin-jose).

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Here I get the original orientation of the image file and then build out a canvas with appropriate rotation correction. We then set the correctly rotated image as preview.

```
function imagePreview(input,elm) {
    // image file
    var file = input.files[0]; 

    if (!file.type.match('image/jpeg.*')) {
        // image is not a jpeg, do something?
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var exif = piexif.load(e.target.result);
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function () {
            //get original orientation of the uploaded image
            var orientation = exif["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.Orientation];

            // Build a temperory canvas to manipulate image to required orientation
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            ctx.save();
            if (orientation == 2) {
                x = -canvas.width;
                ctx.scale(-1, 1);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                x = -canvas.width;
                y = -canvas.height;
                ctx.scale(-1, -1);
            } else if (orientation == 4) {
                y = -canvas.height;
                ctx.scale(1, -1);
            } else if (orientation == 5) {
                canvas.width = image.height;
                canvas.height = image.width;
                ctx.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height / canvas.width);
                ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
                y = -canvas.width;
                ctx.scale(1, -1);
            } else if (orientation == 6) {
                canvas.width = image.height;
                canvas.height = image.width;
                ctx.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height / canvas.width);
                ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
            } else if (orientation == 7) {
                canvas.width = image.height;
                canvas.height = image.width;
                ctx.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height / canvas.width);
                ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
                x = -canvas.height;
                ctx.scale(-1, 1);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                canvas.width = image.height;
                canvas.height = image.width;
                ctx.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height / canvas.width);
                ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
                x = -canvas.height;
                y = -canvas.width;
                ctx.scale(-1, -1);
            }
            ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
            ctx.restore();

            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

            // set the preview image to your element
            $(elm).css("background-image","url('"+dataURL+"')");
        };
        image.src = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}


$("#settings_img").on("change",function(){
    imagePreview(this,"#settings_img_elm");
});
```

**Make sure to include this library first:** https://github.com/hMatoba/piexifjs

**I got help from the documentation:** https://readthedocs.org/projects/piexif/downloads/pdf/latest/

Comment: if I substitute  this code in my javascript file in place of the above given code then will everything will work properly???

Comment: @Jeffrin Jose Yes. Please try that

Comment: i did try but the preview image is only not vissible

Comment: is there any other factor that must be affecting this

Comment: @JeffrinJose did you include the library properly?

Comment: no i didnt include any library how should i do that

Comment: i didnt include any library do ineed to download this github file??

Comment: @JeffrinJose in the github repo I linked in my answer download the latest piexifjs zip, extract contents, you will find a piexif.js file include that in your html

Comment: @ Sapnesh Naik will giving this command on my composer do the work "npm install piexifjs@1.0.4 "

Comment: You can try that, if it does not work then you need to include the js file manually