# How to change exif data on image upload in js

Tags: javascript, image, exif

I'm building a web app with javascript.

When uploading a photo from my phone its rotated by 90°. 
Is there a way to change the orientation in the exif data of the file before saving it in the database?

Comment: In a place where you perform request to database (after parsing image exif data) simply modify orientation. OR when geting values from DB override the values.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59517195/1195615

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust the orientation of a image in order to show proper preview of the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495684/how-to-adjust-the-orientation-of-a-image-in-order-to-show-proper-preview-of-the)