# Using Jpeg-autorotate npm module to rotate image based on EXIF Data javascript

Tags: javascript, image, npm, onload, exif

When I upload an image in my web app it shows sideways so I am trying to use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-autorotate) to rotate an image based on the EXIF data.

My code looks like this:

```
 <template>
  <div :class="$style.form247">
    <Canvas :url="image" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)" />
      <div :class="$style.file">
      Choose file
      <input :class="$style.input" type="file" @change="onFileUpload">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import Canvas from './Canvas'

const jo = require('jpeg-autorotate')
const options = {quality: 100}



export default {
  props: ['value'],
  components: {
    Canvas
  },
  data() {
    return {
      image: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFileUpload(event) {
      const selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
      const reader = new FileReader()


        const myBuffer = jo.rotate(selectedFile, options)
        .then(({buffer, orientation, dimensions, quality}) => {
          console.log(`Orientation was ${orientation}`)
          console.log(`Dimensions after rotation: ${dimensions.width}x${dimensions.height}`)
          console.log(`Quality: ${quality}`)
          // ...Do whatever you need with the resulting buffer...
          return buffer
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('An error occurred when rotating the file: ' + error.message)
        })

      reader.onload = (e) => this.image = e.target.result



      reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile)

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I try to run my application I get an error saying that *jo.rotate* function doesn't have a path or buffer as a parameter, which is what I thought the *selectedFile* constant was. Basically I am confused as how to use this module within my code. I looked at the examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-autorotate) in the **sample usage** section, but I am confused as how to how to use the rotate function. Like am I supposed to store the results of the jo.rotate function in a variable like this?

```
const myBuffer = jo.rotate(selectedFile, options)
.then(({buffer, orientation, dimensions, quality}) => {
  console.log(`Orientation was ${orientation}`)
  console.log(`Dimensions after rotation: ${dimensions.width}x${dimensions.height}`)
  console.log(`Quality: ${quality}`)
  // ...Do whatever you need with the resulting buffer...
  return buffer
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('An error occurred when rotating the file: ' + error.message)
})
```

and if so do I pass it to the readAsDataURL function like so reader.readAsDataURL(myBuffer)?

I am also pretty sure that where I currently have the *jo.rotate* function is wrong, but I am not sure about the correct place to put since I am new to javascript. I have the feeling that it needs to go in the *reader.onload* function, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I hope jpeg-autorotate only runs in backend (Nodejs). If you need client side exif please go through following link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images

Comment: `jpeg-autorotate` doesn't work in the browser. See comment [here](https://github.com/johansatge/jpeg-autorotate/issues/6).

Comment: @RobC Thanks I didn't realize that it didn't work on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately jpeg-autorotate doesn't work in browser. You will need to use exif parsing library to extract orientation and then rotate the image yourself with css `transform:rotate(...)` or canvas.

For the orientation parsing I would recommend [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr). It's fast at that and can handle hundreds of photos without crashing the browser or taking a long time :). Plus there's neat simple API and you feed it with pretty much anything -  element, URL, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, even base64 url or string and more.

```js
exifr.orientation(file).then(val => {
  console.log('orientation:', val)
})
```

This gives you an integer from 1 to 8 (learn more about [these values here](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html))