# How to make my upload pictures from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried soo many ways changing the margin and other things in my css in my code but nothing works.
The only thing that i am asking is where should i change the code to make my pictures orientation after I upload from vertical to horizontal.

Here is the code:

```js
function showMyImage(fileInput) {
    var files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {           
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;     
        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }           
        var img=document.createElement("img");
        img.style.width = "20%";
        img.style.marginTop = "10px";
        img.alt = "image";
        img.classList.add("thumbnail");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) { 
            return function(e) { 
                aImg.src = e.target.result; 
            }; 
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        var gallery = document.querySelector(".gallery");
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.display = "inline-block";
        div.appendChild(img);
        gallery.appendChild(div);
    }    
}

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
 output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

const buttonPrintOrSaveDocument = document.querySelector(
    ".button-print-or-save-document"
);

function printOrSave() {
    window.print();
}

buttonPrintOrSaveDocument.addEventListener("click", printOrSave);
```

```css
label textarea{
        vertical-align: top;i
    }

    div { text-align: left; }



.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.gallery > div {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.gallery img {
  display: inline-block;
  
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 5px;
}



.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center"> DATABASE </h1>

<h3> <b>Diametri i gypit: </b> </h3>                        

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="63" max="1800" value="63" class="slider" id="myRange"> 
  <h4 align="left"> fi ɸ : <span id="demo"></span> mm</h4>
</div>

<label for="lang"><b> Materiali Gypit </b> </label>
<select name="Materiali" Id="lang">
  <option value="Azbest">Azbest</option>
  <option value="GRP">GRP</option>
  <option value="Pllastik">Pllastik</option>
  <option value="Heker Cingtun">Heker Cingtun</option>
</select>

<div>
   <p> <b> Anëtarët: </b></p> <textarea rows="5" cols="20"  ></textarea>
</div>

<label>     
<p><label for="w3review" value="Fshati"> <b> Fshati: </b></label></p>
<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="2" cols="20"> </textarea>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<p><label for="w3review" value="Përshkrimi"> <b> Përshkrimi: </b> </label></p>
<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="80"> </textarea>
<! -- Upload picture --> 

<p> <b> Ngarko foto: </b> </p>
<input type="file" accept="image/*"  onchange="showMyImage(this)" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" />
<br/>
<div class="gallery"></div>
<br/>
<img id="thumbnil"  src="your_image_url" width="300" height="200" alt="image"/>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>    
</br>                       
</br>
<button class="button-print-or-save-document">Ruaj</button>
```

If anyone could help me I'd appreciate that.

Comment: You mean [rotate with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)?

Comment: Yes sir. 

Somehow i can align them side by side. I have watched this : "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp" but i am a newbie so i am still learning.

Comment: If you want to rotate the image with CSS it's as simple a a `transform: rotate(90deg)`, if you want to have the image itself rotated, you might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images

Comment: No sir. As i mentioned before I don't want to rotate the images after it is uploaded. 

I want after i upload the images to be aligned side by side so in horizontal position and not in vertical as it is now.

Comment: First, I'm not a sir, second, aren't these two scenarios you have described the same?

Comment: NO. 

As i mentioned before you said to rotate the images so my question it is not to rotate the images after i uploaded. The only thing that i am asking is to align them side by side just like columns and not to be shown in vertical as it is now.

Comment: What is unclear about the w3schools link you posted?

Comment: you should update the question, now everyone is assuming that you want to rotate the pictures

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Defekt</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
      <style>                                                 
         label textarea{
         vertical-align: top;i
         }
         div { text-align: left; }
         .thumbnail {
         display: block;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
         }
         .gallery {
         display: flex;
         /*flex-wrap: wrap; */
         margin-top: 10px;
         }
         .gallery > div {
         margin-right: 10px;
         }
         .gallery img {
         display: inline-block;
         object-fit: cover;
         margin: 5px;
         }
         .slidecontainer {
         width: 100%;
         }
         .slider {
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         width: 100%;
         height: 25px;
         background: #d3d3d3;
         outline: none;
         opacity: 0.7;
         -webkit-transition: .2s;
         transition: opacity .2s;
         }
         .slider:hover {
         opacity: 1;
         }
         .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         appearance: none;
         width: 25px;
         height: 25px;
         background: #04AA6D;
         cursor: pointer;
         }
         .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
         width: 25px;
         height: 25px;
         background: #04AA6D;
         cursor: pointer;
         }
      </style>
      <h1 align="center"> DATABASE </h1>
      <h3> <b>Diametri i gypit: </b> </h3>
      <div class="slidecontainer">
         <input type="range" min="63" max="1800" value="63" class="slider" id="myRange"> 
         <h4 align="left"> fi ɸ : <span id="demo"></span> mm</h4>
      </div>
      <label for="lang"><b> Materiali Gypit </b> </label>
      <select name="Materiali" Id="lang">
         <option value="Azbest">Azbest</option>
         <option value="GRP">GRP</option>
         <option value="Pllastik">Pllastik</option>
         <option value="Heker Cingtun">Heker Cingtun</option>
      </select>
      <div>
         <p> <b> Anëtarët: </b></p>
         <textarea rows="5" cols="20"  ></textarea>
      </div>
      <label>
         <p>
      <label for="w3review" value="Fshati"> <b> Fshati: </b></label></p>
      <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="2" cols="20"> </textarea>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
      <p><label for="w3review" value="Përshkrimi"> <b> Përshkrimi: </b> </label></p>
      <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="80"> </textarea>
      <! -- Upload picture --> 
      <p> <b> Ngarko foto: </b> </p>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*"  onchange="showMyImage(this)" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" />
      <br/>
      <div class="gallery"></div>
      <br/>
      <img id="thumbnil"  src="your_image_url" width="300" height="200" alt="image"/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      </br>                       
      </br>
      <button class="button-print-or-save-document">Ruaj</button>
      <script>
         <!-- Ruaj Foton -- !>
         
         
         function showMyImage(fileInput) {
         var files = fileInput.files;
         for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {           
         var file = files[i];
         var imageType = /image.*/;     
         if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
         continue;
         }           
         var img=document.createElement("img");
         img.style.width = "20%";
         img.style.marginTop = "10px";
         img.alt = "image";
         img.classList.add("thumbnail");
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = (function(aImg) { 
         return function(e) { 
             aImg.src = e.target.result; 
         }; 
         })(img);
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         var gallery = document.querySelector(".gallery");
         var div = document.createElement("div");
         div.style.display = "inline-block";
         div.appendChild(img);
         gallery.appendChild(div);
         }    
         }
         
         
         
         
         
         
         
         var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
         var output = document.getElementById("demo");
         output.innerHTML = slider.value;
         
         slider.oninput = function() {
         output.innerHTML = this.value;
         }
         
         
         
         
         
         const buttonPrintOrSaveDocument = document.querySelector(
         ".button-print-or-save-document"
         );
         
         function printOrSave() {
         window.print();
         }
         
         buttonPrintOrSaveDocument.addEventListener("click", printOrSave);
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can try this way:
in above code i have made change in css part.

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

if I understand your issue correctly then you want to display image horizontally after upload.

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS ASKING!!!! 

Thank you soo much. it works good the shape of images is good but the only thing that is missed is that after i upload images they are too far away from each other. Could it be margin in .gallery img that it's making this distance?

Comment: can you please mark as answer.

Comment: It is said: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." But i upvoted your answer. 
If you can tell me why there's a distance between images after upload please feel free to show the code.

Comment: @Keksi This looks like you are giving people a work assignment with more work after they answer. Please don't use StackOverflow as a code writing service. Learn the basics of CSS - documentation and tuturials are often times freely available on the internet.